# How to enable tree representation of directory entries for ext4?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I need to create several millions of relatively small files (1-1000 short lines at average) having a complex directory layout. That's why it's very important to ensure fast traversal through deeply nested (5-10 levels) directories (each one can contain up to 10,000 entries).

How can I enable support of tree representation of directory entries (which exists starting from ext3) in order to improve file addition performance?

Answer (score 0):

From `man tune2fs`:

> `-O [^]feature[,…] 
>   …
>        dir_index               
>                             Use hashed b-trees to speed up lookups for large directories.

Also, this looks like a case of "I don't actually want to use a file system, but any tree structure that has string keys". So go, and use a tree structure that perfectly fits your needs, and doesn't rely on context switches to get your data, and doesn't offer you features you probably don't need (Journalling, file permissions, creation/access/modification times, …).

To access the data later on, just write a program that either generates the million files from your one tree storage file, or directly write a file system in userland (FUSE) that presents the directory tree "on the fly".